# URL with reference to object from HATEOAS REST response in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, spring-data-rest

I am using @RepositoryRestResource annotation to expose Spring JPA Data as restful service. It works great. However I am struggling with referencing specific entity within angular app.

As known, Spring Data Rest doesn't serialise @Id of the entity, but HAL response contains links to entities (_links.self, _embedded.projects[]._links.self) like in the following example:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/projects{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "projects": [
            {
                "name": "Sample Project",
                "description": "lorem ipsum",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/projects/1f888ada-2c90-48bc-abbe-762d27842124"
                    }
                }
            },
...
```

My Angular application requires to put kind of reference to specific *project* entity in the URL, like http://localhost/angular-app/#/projects/{id}. I don't think using href is good idea. UUID (@Id) seems to be better but is not explicitly listed as a field. This is point I got stuck. After reading tons of articles I came up with 2 ideas, but I don't consider neither of those as a perfect one:

**Idea 1:**
Enable explicitly serialisation of @Id field and just use it to reference to the object.
Caveat: exposing database specific innards to front-end.

**Idea 2:**
Keep @Id field internal and create an extra "business identifier" field which can be used to identify specific object.
Caveat: Extra field in table (wasting space).

I would appreciate your comment on this. Maybe I am just unnecessarily too reserved to implement either of presented ideas, maybe there is a better one.

Answer (score 1):

To give you another option, there is a special wrapper for Angular+Spring Data Rest that could probably help you out:

https://github.com/guylabs/angular-spring-data-rest

Comment: Thanks! I've checked this out already but didn't give me any pointers. Demo doesn't cover my scenario - there is list of categories, but I'd like to see link to sub-view with items for specific category. It requires to pass on in URL either href to category (i.e.: http://localhost:8080/rest/categories/1) or category id (1). The latter is much cleaner for me, but as long as category object doesn't have id field explicitly listed, I have no means to get it.